# Creating a simple csv file: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby, csv

I am struggling with a very basic task of creating a csv file from the ruby core library. I am basically copying the code almost exactly:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open("~/Desktop/codes.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["id", "code"]
  csv << ["TESTCODE01", "CODE001"]
end
```

And when I execute this code, I receive the following error:

```
csv.rb:641:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ~/Desktop/codes.csv (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I have an empty csv file that I'm trying to write to on my Desktop but somehow it errors out. I know this has to be something simple that I'm not doing. Can someone point out what Im doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expecting something like [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) but you're not running in a shell.  Instead do something on the order of:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open(Dir.home + "/Desktop/codes.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["id", "code"]
  csv << ["TESTCODE01", "CODE001"]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out!